# Is there any benefit applying before the deadline?

Tags: application

From what I have seen, academic position usually have 1-2 months deadline.
I know that for non-academic positions if a suitable candidate is found, the position may be filled in advance.

Does applying one month or some weeks before give particular advantages? Is it risky to apply close to the deadline?

Answer (score 2):

Surely country dependent. For **Germany**: There is no difference in applying early or just in time. The review process for all applications does not start before the deadline is passed. I you are one day late you may or may not be considered - I think more often than not you application will not be considered if too late.

Comment: I was considering applying weeks before, I do not want to risk not being considered applying after it. I was just worried that in the time between now and the actual deadline, someone with an suitable background would apply causing the premature ending of the applications.

Answer (score 1):

Can be both ways. For some positions, applications are evaluated after the deadline, some positions are open until filled. My impression is that if a position has a strict and close deadline and a formal application procedure, it is usually of the former kind.

Comment: Some position announcements state 'applications will be considered until the position is filled' or some similar wording (depending on labor laws in that country).

Answer (score 1):

In general, all applications are reviewed together after the application deadline. Thus, there isn't any particular advantage to applying months or weeks early, nor is there any particular risk to applying close to the deadline (although it's always good to aim to be finished early in case unforseen delays arise).

It is a good idea to contact people you are applying to work with before the deadline, but this typically doesn't require a full application to be submitted.